# laravel hasOneThrough with trashed does not remove the softdelete scope of intermediate

Tags: php, laravel

How to get all the relational records of timeslots when intermediate(`hasOneThrough`) has soft deletes.

**1.** Attendance Model `Attendance.php`

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Attendance extends Model
{

    protected $fillable = [
        'tutor_id',
        'center_timeslot_id',
        // other attributes are ommited
    ];

    public function timeslot()
    {
        return $this->hasOneThrough(
            Timeslot::class,
            CenterTimeslot::class,
            'id',
            'id', // primary key on timeslots table...
            'center_timeslot_id', //local key of this table to primary of centerTimeslots table
            'timeslot_id' //local key on centertimeslots table of target table timeslot
        )
        ->withTrashed();//this does not work
    }
}
```

**2.** CenterTimeslot Model `CenterTimeslot.php`

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

class CenterTimeslot extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes;
    protected $fillable = [
        'center_id', 'timeslot_id', 'capacity'
        // other attributes are ommited
    ];

    public function timeslot()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Timeslot::class);
    }
}
```

**3.** Finally Timeslot Model `Timeslot.php`

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Carbon\Carbon;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Timeslot extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        // other attributes are ommited

    ];
}
```

So if any record is soft deleted that is in center_timeslot_table we can not retrieve the model though applying `withTrashed()` as it only works on direct model on in the through table. So the soft deletes gets still applied as defined in CenterTimeslot Model
So there is no way to get the records.

But I can trick the query builder to have the method like this which does retrieve the records
`Attendance.php`

```
public function timeslot()
    {
        return $this->hasOneThrough(
            Timeslot::class,
            CenterTimeslot::class,
            'id',
            'id', // primary key on timeslots table...
            'center_timeslot_id', //local key of this table to primary of centerTimeslots table
            'timeslot_id' //local key on centertimeslots table of target table timeslot
        )
        ->withTrashed()
        ->orWhere(function ($query) {
            $query->whereNotNull('center_timeslots.deleted_at');
        });
```

Sot it returns the record but I am not satisfied with the hack. So if someone can give some light or a better workaround will be good.

Comment: You need to sure you are using softDelete trait in all models you are soft deleting.

Answer (score 0):

I face the same issue when my project was in the middle of development and my conclusion after searching on this is:
The [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#defining-custom-intermediate-table-models) says at first coming note that:[image]

And you make your pivot table a model therefore SoftDeletes are working.And ***withTrashed()*** is working for ***Timeslot::class*** but not for pivot table (***CenterTimeslot***) because laravel was not expecting a model here.

According to [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#defining-custom-intermediate-table-models), your Central or pivot table line should be

***use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Pivot;***

***class CenterTimeslot extends Pivot***

instead of

***class CenterTimeslot extends Model***

in this way, there will be the issue of ***SoftDeletes***

In my case, I solve this by creating to classes one is extending from ***Pivot*** (which I am using for relation calls) and the other from ***Model*** (using where SoftDeletes or as a model is required) but I am not sure that this is the proper way or not but is working fine. I Will appreciate it if someone adds a proper way to deal with it but for the current time, it is working as required.

***Note:*** Make the pivot class name different from the model and if the table name is different then you can define $table separately in pivot class.